# What questions am I not allowed to ask?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I really don't want to ask a question that will get me temporarily banned.

Am I allowed to ask for reputation? Am I allowed to ask if I can get people to give me some feedback on my posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to specify directly to your original question:

> I Really don´t want to get in trouble for asking a question on this web site that will get me temporarily banned?

I can hardly imagine that any question (assuming that it is on topic) would get you banned. Your question might be down-voted if the readers won't like it, but as long as in general your question is following the "[be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback)" rule, you don't have to worry about bans.

> Am I allowed to ask for reputations

No - you will earn reputation when your questions and answers will be upvoted

> am I allowed to ask if I can get people to give me some questions on my posts?

No - If you are an expert on any topic, we will welcome your input, however don't advertise yourself (with a question) as such person, instead post your answer on that topic, whenever they will appear on this website. Please note, that you can add tags that you are interested in to the list of "watched tags".

Comment: RE: "*I can hardly imagine that any question...would get you banned."* - It's possible to hit a question/answer ban/block if the quality of your previous posts are low. This is an automatic, system-imposed, and temporary stop to make the affected user consider their past posts, and work to improve them.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of information is available in the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help).

In particular, I recommend checking out [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)